# After upgrade my WordPress version 5.4.4 to 5.6, I can not set my homepage

Tags: homepage, upgrade

I had a machine use the wamp64 server and PHP 7.3.5 to build my WordPress site,
and I just click the upgrade button to set my WordPress version 5.4.4 to 5.6 form the dashboard.

After the upgrade is finished, the homepage didn't show correctly.

I set the homepage information form "Settings -> Your homepage displays -> A static page -> Homepage" and choose the page I create it public.

But when I browse the homepage it show :
[image: ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT]

The following way that I had already try :

- Restart the wamp64 server.
- Stop all the plugin which is running in my WordPress.
- Change the theme.

And it also can't show my homepage.

I had use the plugin "WP Downgrade" to recover my website to 5.4.4 and it works fine.

Is there any idea can let me upgrade my WordPress to v5.6 and fix or trace this problem?

Comment: perhaps make a copy and try to upgrade again - enable the PHP error log via wp_config.php settings and try to refresh permalinks in the admin .

Comment: Can you try `curl -D - https://your-site.com` and it'll show you the exact response from the server. Or you can probably see this in your browser debug tools. That should show you what the invalid redirect is.

Comment: But I'd guess it's a redirect from a public URL to localhost. Can you check your site and blog URLs in the dashboard or in the database please, under Settings General?

Comment: Hi @QStudio , I had already try to upgrade again, and set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in wp-config.php, but I don't know where can I see the log info. And I found that permalinks in the admin if I set default, my WordPress works fine. But rollback to custom structure, it will make the same issue that homepage can't work correctly.

Comment: Hi @Rup , I try the curl and get `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`, and check URL setting in both dashboard and DB, the setting is correct... thanks for your advice !

Comment: Yes, it's the "Location" line in the curl output that's the problem I'd guess.

Comment: If the site loads without custom permalinks, the issue is probably that WP can't write the .htaccess file - perhaps permissions - you might be able to create this manually from the instructions here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: I try to revise the .htaccess file by the instructions, but it doesn't take effect... the issue still exists. I will try to build a new website to check this problem will exist or not. Thank you for your response.